# Processor wrong using Memtest86

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, memtest86+

I am running MemTest86 4.2 on a Mac Pro that has ubuntu installed on it. The /proc/cpuinfo file tells me it has two Intel Xeon X5550 installed as I expected. MemTest86 has Intel Core i7 2660Mhz in the top left. I am curious as to why there is a difference between the processors? I am running intensive computations and need to know the exact make and model.

Comment: Which version (release) of memtest86+ are you running? Maybe it just hasn't been updated to include that specific CPU in its builtin database? Also, is this a problem, or just curiosity? Please **[edit]** to indicate the answers.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue with `memtest86+` when troubleshooting RAM on some Xeon-based DELL workstations. It would show Sandy Bridge i7 instead of Xeon. Changing the version to newer memtest as indicated by Micheal should solve this issue.

Comment: Actually, the X5550 came out in Q1 2009 [Intel Ark](http://ark.intel.com/sv/products/37106/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X5550-8M-Cache-2_66-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI), and Memtest86+ 4.20 is dated [January 2011](http://www.memtest.org/#downcode), so I'd expect it to know about that one. Curious.